# How can I reload the content of component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular2-routing

At one moment of **runtime** my url looks like

```
http://localhost:4200/personal/51c50594-a95c-4a18-ac7b-b0521d67af96
```

I want to go to a page with only a different `GUID` and different content.

```
http://localhost:4200/personal/{otherGuid}
```

This is not working:

```
this.router.navigate(['/personal',new_ guid]);
```

How can I achieve this in angular 2 ?

Comment: have you tried relative navigation? `this.router.navigate([new_guid], { relativeTo: this.route });`  this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634237/how-do-i-navigate-to-a-sibling-route

Comment: @user7552, it's not working. Only the url is changed.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836674/how-do-i-re-render-a-component-manually

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai you want to just navigate to the new page with its content right , sorry but i am not able to understand the question  can you breif it for me

Comment: I am on some page with url `http://localhost:4200/personal/51c50594-a95c-4a18-ac7b-b0521d67af96` and page has some content. When i click a button i want to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/personal/{otherGuid}` and also change the content of page based on `guid`.

Comment: I think what is not working for him, is that the content is not changing, but the url is. if this is the case, then the link @Vega provided should probably solve this problem. The component has already rendered, and only the `param` has changed. So, you'd only need to subscribe to it and change it accordingly like the answers shown from that link.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai this might seem hacky but you can call the `destroy` method of the component and then `re-render`

Comment: @user7552, yes, that's the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below,

```
 ....
  this.router.navigate(['personal', id]);
 ....

 constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, router: Router){
  this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
     // this will be fired when you change the guid,
     // use the new param to reload component..
  })
 }
```

check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1klETnFnDMcBXCH66Fl9?p=preview)!!

Comment: Yes, this is also one solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836674/how-do-i-re-render-a-component-manually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate to intermediate route `/personal` and in that page you can get the parameter and based on parameter again using switch case you can navigate to other route. In the latter part if you don't want to change the route displayed in url bar you can do this by using this code

```
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

`skipLocationChange: true` Navigates without pushing a new state into history.

for your reference you can check this [link](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)